# Nativescript-Vue: 'tns preview' error with loading Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nativescript-vue, tns

For a trivia app I'm developing for mobile, I'm using Nativescript-Vue to develop. The app runs fine and without errors when running it with xcode iOS emulator. However, when I try to run a preview (with the terminal command: 'tns preview') the app runs but when I try to start a game the app throws an error:

```
CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:2129:20: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$store.getters')"

found in

---> <App> at App.vue
       <Frame>
        <Root>
LOG from device iPhone CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:2129:20: [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$store.getters')"
```

I'm trying to run it using the playground app on my iPhone SE and scanning the qr-code. I'm thinking it has something to do with the app not being able to access the VueX store or something. But I'm kind of at a loss. I've seen the 'tns preview' command work, but that was with a Vue app without Vuex. Do you know what I might be doing wrong?

UPDATE: after adding `Vue.prototype.$store = store` in main.js, I get a slightly different error:

```
CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:2129:20: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.$store.getters is not an Object. (evaluating 'val in this.$store.getters')"
```

Still don't know what can be wrong, but I do know the tns preview works when disabling / commenting out all things related to the store in the code, so it defintely got something to do with that. Please help, I really want to show this app to somebody on their phone.

Comment: this.$store.getters should be a state in your store. Could you show your store definition code?

Comment: hey thanks for the reply but I decided a few days after I posted this question to switch to Vue Native instead of NativeScript and rewrite my app for that, because in general it is showing a lot less buggy behaviour also with regards to VueX, when trying to preview on a phone device. At least for me, could be because I'm more familiar with the Expo app then with NativeScript. In any case it is working now a lot smoother.

Comment: Has anyone else experienced this issue, I was really hoping to get an answer here?

Comment: My recommendation would be to use Vue Native instead of NativeScript-Vue. It just seems to work a lot better, when it comes to VueX and quickly being able to preview an app on a phone while still in development. Plus it basically still works in the same way as NativeScript, so converting what you already have doesn't take long.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this problem by adding in `main.js` this line, right after importing store:

```
import store from './store'
Vue.prototype.$store = store
```